# Interpretation of block diagram for proportional feedback system with respect to time

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

Suppose we have a proportional feedback and that the system is modelled by a block diagram i.e

[image]

where C is a constant. Do we think about this as a signal "moving" in time around this loop or is the time the same everywhere inside these blocks and for all signals?

How does one keep track of which t, say for y(t_j), corresponds to u(t_i)?

Comment: Assuming continuous systems, some have pure time delay blocks, typically temperature control systems. Otherwise, systems are assumed to be lumped, so everything is considered to happen concurrently. Digital or hybrid systems sometimes exhibit delays due to the sampling process.

Comment: For the most part, you typically treat a feedback system as a system where everything happens simultaneously. Realistically, yes, there could be some delay in your system from one block to another. However, we characterize feedback systems with transfer functions and utilize the Laplace Domain, which is different from the Time Domain. You _could_ keep track of behavior of the feedback system at time _t_ if you go one step at a time in the block diagram.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, if you switch a voltage onto a resistor/capacitor circuit, the voltages and currents are transients and take time to settle to new values. The same happens in control systems. Motors do not change speed instantaneously - if you apply a step change to a block, the output will have some sort of transient unless it's a pure gain.

Comment: @user21312 if you delete your comments, the thread of the discussion becomes disjointed.

Comment: @Chu yea sorry I was tying to find a better formulation.

Comment: @KingDuken so block diagrams never refer to the time domain? I think they could

Comment: @user21312 They are time variant sure but we mainly use the Laplace Domain to look at its stability. You can use the time domain to determine the quantitative value of something. We use the Laplace Domain to make the math easier as well.

Comment: @KingDuken so you would say it it a bad idea to think about block diagrams for the time domain perspective?

Comment: I believe it depends on what you're trying to do. Like I mentioned, the s-domain is determining stability (i.e. making sure there's no RHP that will suck at all the energy in the known universe and create a cataclysm to try to become more stable). However, if you're using something like a filter in your circuit and wish to know the voltage across a capacitor or something, then the time domain is a good tool but the math is more difficult. Another example of finding a quantitative value is if you're trying to relate the speed of revolution depending on input voltage of a motor.

Comment: Not enough info to answer. Is your block diagram in time-domain or frequency-domain?! And what are these blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless time-dependency is specified, assume there isn't any.

Nothing in your diagram seems to mention time at all.  You can therefore assume each block does whatever it does instantly.

Of course in the real world, there will always be some time delays.  Part of knowing how to design good control systems is to know when these delays matter and when they don't.

In general, you want the dominant time constant to come from the plant, with the controller itself being faster.

Comment: I think I got it now. If we think in terms of basic mechanics and u being some force then the y(t) depends on all the u(s) s<t and the u(t) affects the y(t) instantaneously affecting it to move in some fashion in t+d(where new contols are generated for each time in the small intervall) . Is that a good way to think about it?